# What to feed newborn wheel bugs

Tags: diet, insects, live-food

My baby wheel bugs hatched recently, and I'm having a hard time finding food for them.  I tried to make a fruit fly trap with a bottle, a funnel, and some smashed tomato, but I guess it's too cold outside.  Yesterday I brought the trap inside, but I haven't seen any flies yet.  I know I could buy fruit fly cultures, but I don't want to spend any money.

Is there a better trap I can make or a good place I can look to get bugs small enough for my wheel bugs to eat?

Comment: Related [Feeding Leopard Gecko food from outside?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10329)

Comment: It's pretty easy to keep a culture of fruit flies going once you have some to start with. https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2053/can-i-make-my-own-substrate-to-keep-fruit-flies-alive

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia Wheel bugs may be overly sensitive to pesticides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_bug#Ecological_significance)

> Wheel bugs are highly regarded by organic gardeners because they consume a variety of insects and their presence indicates a healthy, pesticide-free ecosystem.

As pointed out in the question [Feeding Leopard Gecko food from outside?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10329/feeding-leopard-gecko-food-from-outside) the risk of harm to your pet(s) from wild caught insects in residential areas, is significant.  Purchasing Farm-raised insects or beginning with them to farm your own may be ultimately more cost effective and safer for your pets.

In addition to fruit flies, aphids could form the foundation of a healthy herd to feed your Wheel bugs.

Comment: I keep wheel bugs as an experiment.  I'm not an animal lover, and I'm not really worried about the shortening of their already-short lifespan.  I don't want to spend any money, so looking in the wild seems to be my only choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply leave some fruit leftovers in a spot in your home in a bug container, they will come. I have done it for baby lizards using tomato and orange rinds. I never had a problem with those pests popping up like magic no matter the weather outdoors.

Comment: About a week ago, I took out the funnel in the bottle I mentioned in the question.  It has tomato in it and apple cider vinegar, but I still haven't seen any bugs.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Wheel bugs primarily consume other slow-moving insects, like caterpillars, for example. You may want to consider that as well.

Comment: it had been nice if you provided more information in your answer,this answer is at risk of being deleted because it is very short.

Answer (score 0):

According to Hilton Pond Center, wheel bugs (aka assassins of the insect world) are carnivores, so my guess is they eat smaller bugs. For example ants, flies, etc. But I suggest liquefying the food since they're newborns. Please check your local pet store. I'm not an expert.